# Spark enforce partitioning on read

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that is partitioned like:

```
raw_data/year=2020/month=05/day=01/hour=00/minute=00/xxx.parquet
raw_data/year=2020/month=05/day=01/hour=00/minute=01/xxx.parquet
...
...
raw_data/year=2020/month=05/day=01/hour=01/minute=00/xxx.parquet
...
```

I want to load a large number of partitions (say 1 month period), aggregate them per hour, then save it with the following partitions:

```
processed_data/year=2020/month=05/day=01/hour=00/yyy.parquet
processed_data/year=2020/month=05/day=01/hour=01/yyy.parquet
...
```

I feel like, if Spark can read the dataset such that, each executor reads al of the files under `hour` partition, it would minimize the reshuffling. Is there any way to specify Spark's partition reading pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is as per this document: http://tantusdata.com/spark-shuffle-case-1-partition-by-and-repartition/

`df.repartition...write.partitionBy...` to avoid shuffling and better subsequent read performance.

`Spark partition discovery` on read with base path could help as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to **save** the data in the way you want to read it instead of trying to customize how Spark loads data.

You could read all the data and partition it by *hours* as you like. Probably you need to first create a column like "year-month-day-hour", but then you can repartition your data based on this column.

```scala
df.repartition(col("year-month-day-hour")).write.format("parquet").save(path-to-file)
```

Comment: repartitionBy is a safer option to begin with

Comment: by save, do you mean how it's saved in the raw area of his lake?

Comment: think you need both